# The Git Repositories tab from eclipse it's empty

Tags: java, eclipse, git, repository, egit

I added one repository on eclipse, but when i tried to add a second one both repositories are disappeared. I try to add an existing to view but the eclipse says "1 directories are hidden as they have already been added". How to make they show again?

[image: Print of the problem]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The information message is normal (as explained in [bug 315558](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315558)): you cannot add a repo you already added.

Which is not normal is that the search process comes up empty under `Y:\`, while I assume there are several `repo/.git` directories for you to select.
Try and refine the path: `Y:/path/to/your/second/repo` and see if it is more visible there.

Check also the version of EGit you are using, and try to upgrade to the latest (2.3)